# Best way to design a multilevel hamburger menu?

Tags: mobile, navigation, hamburger

– Do you know about a usability study that has compared how to best present deeper navigation levels inside a hamburger menu used on mobile web sites?

As I see it there are two main patterns:

| **Accordion/Tree view** | **Drilldown** |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an articel about the topict https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-subnavigation/

The guidelines and conclusions is summarised as:

> If you have less than 6 subcategories for all primary categories, then
> a submenu or accordion in the global navigation may be appropriate.
>
> If you have between 6 and 15 subcategories for at least some of your
> primary categories, then consider a section menu.
>
> With more than 15 subcategories per primary category, consider a
> category landing page.

Comment: Boy, that article was almost too spot on. Spooky :)